# Slide out the link when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to make it where a button is clicked a div will slide out containing a link to another website. I have supplied the current code I have but when the button is clicked it doesn't slide out. It slides but appears under the button.

```js
$('.button1').on('click', function() {
  animateDiv();
})

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27 && $('.inner').hasClass('visible')) {
    animateDiv();
  }
})

function animateDiv() {
  $('.inner').toggleClass('visible');
  $('.inner').animate({
    width: 'toggle',
  }, 350);
}
```

```css
.toolbar {
  position: right;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.inner {
  float: right;
  display: none;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2780E3;
  border-color: #2780E3;
}

.btn-lg,
.btn-group-lg > .btn {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.171875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='toolbar'>
  <div>
    <button class="button1 btn btn-primary btn-lg">Slide it</button>
  </div>
  <div class="inner is-hidden">
    <a href="http:///www.google.com">Google</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what slide out looks like ???

Comment: @A.ANoman becarefull while doing changes, you changed his code and make it no more working

Comment: @TemaniAfif  Sorry for mistake